# Interior of $C = \{x\in\boldsymbol{R}^3\ |\ -1\le x_1\le1, -1\le x_2\le1, x_3=0\}$

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

I am trying to understand why the interior of the following square in the $\left(x_1,x_2\right)$-plane in $\boldsymbol{R}^3$:

$C = \{x\in\boldsymbol{R}^3\ |\ -1\le x_1\le1, -1\le x_2\le1, x_3=0\}$

is an empty set.

By definition, the interior of a subset $S$ of points of a topological space $X$ consists of all points of $S$ that do not belong to the boundary of $S$. However, this definition does not result in $\boldsymbol{\rm int}\ C=\emptyset$ since excluding the boundary of the square can be considered the interior of $C$ and is not empty. Could someone help me have a better understanding of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the boundary of a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a different meaning than the boundary of the square in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In fact, the boundary of $C$ equals $C$. This is because any ball around any point of $C$ will have elements whose third coordinate is nonzero, and thus will have elements outside of $C$.

We can also see that the interior is empty without looking at the boundary. Recall that the interior of a set $S$ is the set of all points $x$ for which there is an open set $U$ which satisfies $x\in U \subseteq C$. Since every open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will contain an open ball, and every one of these open balls will contain elements whose third component is not zero, we infer that every nonempty open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will contain points outside of $C$. Therefore $C$ does not have any interior points.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick answer. Could you please also comment on the relative interior of $C$?

Comment: @Ahmad I've edited my post. Please let me know if there's any confusion.